# I cannot use npm anymore

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, nvm

To resolve an error during the development of an application, I changed my version of 'node' to an earlier version. When I switched back to my usual version (20.10.0), I could no longer use npm commands like "npm install".
I then decided to uninstall node, npm (even VSCode and Git) then reinstalled them, but the problem is still there.
I also added the path to my node file to my environment variables, but that didn't change anything.
Here's what my errors look like:

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path C:\Users\[myUserName]\Desktop\[myProject]\node_modules\esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command bash -c node install.js
npm ERR! /bin/bash: line 1: node: command not found
```

I already checked node and npm version:

```
node -v
>v20.10.0
npm -v
>10.2.5
```

I don't know if it matters, but I use nvm and I develop under windows.

Comment: Try using the Node Version Manger: [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/releases).
Which error did you get? If you get `npm is not recognized` then you need to add the binary to your environmental variables

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my message with the error.

Comment: When asking a question. Try to incorporate things you've already tried. For instance, did you try `node -v`, `npm -v`?

Comment: Yes, they are well installed

Comment: Are you running these command in system terminal or VSCode terminal? (the `npm i` and  `npm -v`). Because sometimes the VScode terminal acts weird when updating `PATH` variables even after terminal refresh/window refresh. If this doesn't work try removing the `node_modules` folder

Comment: I run these command in both my system terminal and my VSCode terminal and the output is the same

Comment: I've had lots of problems with npm and node on Windows, so I switched to WSL and run my ubuntu terminal without any problems.  see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about

Comment: Yes I already remove node_modules but it didn't work sadly
@ivanmarchenko I try this and let you know if it works

Comment: Does this error only occur for the `esbuild` module or different ones?

Comment: @Joerie Oh, I din't notice it only occurs for esbuild module. Do you have an idea?